# iOS TestFlight build cannot purchase products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, testflight, storekit

Hi I'm new to iOS and I am working on my 1st App but encountered some in-app-purchase issues.

I have some consumable in-app-purchase products in my App, recently I tested them on both Debug and Release build configurations and they worked as expected: a message says success and a related number(similar to diamonds in games) updated.

However, when I tested it on a TestFlight build. The products can be loaded, a dialogue asked me to enter password(I didn't see this step in Debug/Release tests), and finally it showed a success message. But the problem is **I didn't see the related number updated**.

Is it expected in TestFlight build? If it is, how can I ensure the IAP work as expected in production environment?

I did some research but didn't find what I want, so far I have tried to find something wrong in my code but no luck.
My expectation is my TF build work as well as Debug/Release

```
func purchase(_ product: SKProduct, onSuccess: Binding<Product?>) {
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

    let cancelBag = CancelBag(#function)
    purchasedSubject
        .sink { prod in
            onSuccess.wrappedValue = prod
            cancelBag.cancel()
        }
        .store(in: cancelBag)
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    transactions.forEach { tx in
        switch tx.transactionState {
        case .purchasing:
            print("StoreKit: purchasing")
        case .purchased:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(tx)

            if let product = Product.allCases.first(where: { $0.rawValue == tx.payment.productIdentifier }) {
                purchasedSubject.send(product)
                print("StoreKit: purchased \(product.rawValue)")
            } else {
                print("StoreKit: product not found")
            }
        case .failed:
            print("StoreKit: failed")
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(tx)
        case .restored:
            print("StoreKit: restored")
        case .deferred:
            print("StoreKit: deffered")
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```